# How do I properly support STARTTLS with aiosmtpd?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiosmtpd

I have the following server taken almost directly from the aiosmtpd docs:

```
import asyncio
import ssl
from aiosmtpd.controller import Controller


class ExampleHandler:
    async def handle_RCPT(self, server, session, envelope, address, rcpt_options):
        if not address.endswith('@example.com'):
            return '550 not relaying to that domain'
        envelope.rcpt_tos.append(address)
        return '250 OK'

    async def handle_DATA(self, server, session, envelope):
        print(f'Message from {envelope.mail_from}')
        print(f'Message for {envelope.rcpt_tos}')
        print(f'Message data:\n{envelope.content.decode("utf8", errors="replace")}')
        print('End of message')
        return '250 Message accepted for delivery'

context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
controller = Controller(ExampleHandler(), port=8026, ssl_context=context)
controller.start()

input('Press enter to stop')
controller.stop()
```

However, when I start this server and try to send an email to it using swaks:

```
echo 'Testing' | swaks --to wayne@example.com --from "something@example.org" --server localhost --port 8026 -tls
```

It times out after 30s. If I remove the `ssl_context=context` from the server and `-tls` from the client then it sends the mail fine.

Additionally, when I try to connect via telnet and just send `EHLO whatever` then the server actually closes the connection.

What's the correct way to implement an aiosmtpd server that supports tls?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Building upon Wayne's own answer, here's how to create a STARTTLS server with aiosmtpd.

### 1. Create an SSL context

For testing, use the following command to generate a self-signed certificate for `localhost`:

`openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -nodes -subj '/CN=localhost'`

Load it into Python using the `ssl` module:

```
import ssl
context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
context.load_cert_chain('cert.pem', 'key.pem')
```

### 2. Pass SSL context to aiosmtpd

Create a subclass of aiosmtpd's Controller that passes this context as the `tls_context` to `SMTP`:

```
from aiosmtpd.smtp import SMTP
from aiosmtpd.controller import Controller

class ControllerTls(Controller):
    def factory(self):
        return SMTP(self.handler, require_starttls=True, tls_context=context)
```

### 3. Run it

Instantiate this controller with a handler and start it. Here, I use aiosmtpd's own `Debugging` handler:

```
from aiosmtpd.handlers import Debugging
controller = ControllerTls(Debugging(), port=1025)
controller.start()
input('Press enter to stop')
controller.stop()
```

### 4. Test it

Either configure a local mail client to send to `localhost:1025`, or use `swaks`:

`swaks -tls -t test --server localhost:1025`

... or use `openssl s_client` to talk to the server after the initial `STARTTLS` command has been issued:

`openssl s_client -crlf -CAfile cert.pem -connect localhost:1025 -starttls smtp`

### The full code

The code below additionally tests the server using swaks, and it also shows how to create a TLS-on-connect server (as in Wayne's answer).

```
import os
import ssl
import subprocess
from aiosmtpd.smtp import SMTP
from aiosmtpd.controller import Controller
from aiosmtpd.handlers import Debugging

# Create cert and key if they don't exist
if not os.path.exists('cert.pem') and not os.path.exists('key.pem'):
    subprocess.call('openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem ' +
                    '-days 365 -nodes -subj "/CN=localhost"', shell=True)

# Load SSL context
context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
context.load_cert_chain('cert.pem', 'key.pem')

# Pass SSL context to aiosmtpd
class ControllerStarttls(Controller):
    def factory(self):
        return SMTP(self.handler, require_starttls=True, tls_context=context)

# Start server
controller = ControllerStarttls(Debugging(), port=1025)
controller.start()
# Test using swaks (if available)
subprocess.call('swaks -tls -t test --server localhost:1025', shell=True)
input('Running STARTTLS server. Press enter to stop.\n')
controller.stop()

# Alternatively: Use TLS-on-connect
controller = Controller(Debugging(), port=1025, ssl_context=context)
controller.start()
# Test using swaks (if available)
subprocess.call('swaks -tlsc -t test --server localhost:1025', shell=True)
input('Running TLSC server. Press enter to stop.\n')
controller.stop()
```

Answer (score 3):

I was close. I figured from the fact that I could connect via telnet, but `EHLO hostname` would disconnect that the server was trying to require a TLS connection ahead of time.

When I examined `swaks --help` I found that there was a slightly different option that would probably do what I wanted:

```
--tlsc, --tls-on-connect
    Initiate a TLS connection immediately on connection.  Following common convention,
    if this option is specified the default port changes from 25 to 465, though this can
    still be overridden with the --port option.
```

When I tried that, I still got an error:

```
$ echo 'Testing' | swaks --to wayne@example.com --from "something@example.com" --server localhost --port 8026 -tlsc
=== Trying localhost:8026...
=== Connected to localhost.
*** TLS startup failed (connect(): error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0))
```

Through some of my perusal of the Python ssl documentation, I noticed the [`load_cert_chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_cert_chain) method. It turned out that this was exactly what I needed. Following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10176685/344286) I generated a totally insecure self-signed certificate:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -nodes -subj '/CN=localhost'
```

Then I added this line:

```
context.load_cert_chain('cert.pem', 'key.pem')
```

And now I'm able to send email. For the <strike>lazy</strike>curious, here's the entire server code:

```
import asyncio
import ssl
from aiosmtpd.controller import Controller


class ExampleHandler:
    async def handle_RCPT(self, server, session, envelope, address, rcpt_options):
        if not address.endswith('@example.com'):
            return '550 not relaying to that domain'
        envelope.rcpt_tos.append(address)
        return '250 OK'

    async def handle_DATA(self, server, session, envelope):
        print(f'Message from {envelope.mail_from}')
        print(f'Message for {envelope.rcpt_tos}')
        print(f'Message data:\n{envelope.content.decode("utf8", errors="replace")}')
        print('End of message')
        return '250 Message accepted for delivery'

context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
context.load_cert_chain('cert.pem', 'key.pem')
controller = Controller(ExampleHandler(), port=8026, ssl_context=context)
controller.start()

input('Press enter to stop')
controller.stop()
```

Which can be validated with:

```
echo 'Testing' | swaks --to someone@example.com --from "someone_else@example.org" --server localhost --port 8026 -tlsc
```

Comment: Note that this is not STARTTLS but regular TLS since the connection is not initially plaintext.